# JSDoc: Accept instances of base class and it's child classes in `@type` tag

Tags: javascript, class, phpstorm, webstorm, jsdoc

I have a base class (`Validator`) that is extended by a child class (`ValidatorRequired`).

Then in another class I want to have a collection of instances that may be of base class type (`Validator`) or any of its descendants (`ValidatorRequired`).

However, when I try to create an instance of a child class and place it inside that collection (at `FormField` class constructor), I get a weak warning from PhpStorm: `Assigned expression type ValidatorRequired is not assignable to type Validator`:

[image: PhpStorm inspection "Assigned expression type ValidatorRequired is not assignable to type Validator"]

I suspect the error comes from the fact I've not defined the `@type` tag correctly.

What is the correct way to fix that inspection?

`FormField.js`:

```js
import { ValidatorRequired } from './ValidatorRequired';

export class FormField {
    /**
     * Field's current value.
     *
     * @type {number|string}
     */
    value;

    /**
     * A collection of validators that should be run each time the field is validated.
     *
     * @type {Object.<string, Validator>}
     */
    validators = {};

    constructor({ required }) {
        this.required = Boolean(required);

        // The part after the `=` operator is underlined with grey as a weak warning
        this.validators.validatorRequired = new ValidatorRequired({ formField: this });
    }
}
```

`Validator.js`:

```js
export class Validator {
    /**
     * The field to validate.
     *
     * @type {FormField}
     */
    formField;

    /**
     * @param formField {FormField}
     */
    constructor({ formField }) {
        this.formField = formField;
    }

    /**
     * Validates a field.
     * Should be overridden by child classes.
     *
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    validate() {
        return this.success();
    }

    /**
     * Ends validation with successful result.
     *
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    success() {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Ends validation with an error.
     *
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    error() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

`ValidatorRequired.js`:

```js
import { Validator } from './Validator';

/**
 * A validator that checks for field's value to be non-empty when it is required.
 */
export class ValidatorRequired extends Validator {
    /**
     * Validates a field.
     *
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    validate() {
        // If the field is not required, return success.
        if (!this.formField.required) {
            return this.success();
        }

        // If the value is not falsy, return success.
        if (this.formField.value) {
            return this.success();
        }

        // If all previous checks have failed, return error.
        return this.error();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the error was not in the `@type` tag in JSDoc, rather in how PhpStorm treats the class that is specified there.

I have React library imported somewhere else in my project. And React has a class `Validator` defined. PhpStorm is aware of that and thinks the `Validator` I specified in JSDoc is the `Validator` in React and not my own `Validator`.

This fact is proved when you try going to the definition of class `Validator` through JSDoc comment for `validators` field (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click on the class, or place a cursor at the class and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). If you do that, you get a "Choose Declaration" dialogue window, where all the possible declarations are listed:

[image: "Choose Declaration" dialogue window]

So the solution is to make PhpStorm think the `Validator` specified is 100% my own class. This is easily done by explicitly importing the `Validator`:

`FormField.js`:

```js
import { Validator } from './Validator';
```

This solution has a minor downside: your base class (`Validator`) will be included in the bundle regardless of whether it is used or not. However, I think this has a negligible impact, because:

1. If you use a class that is a descendant from the base class, you certainly will have the base class included in the bundle anyway (class `ValidatorRequired` extends `Validator`).
2. If you don't use any of the descendants right where you document the `@type` tag (class `FormField`), you are probably using them in the descendants of the class that is documenting the usage (`FormField` descendants), or you are doing something wrong.
3. The size of the base class is probably too tiny to bring a vast effect on the bundle.